# Как обработать атрибут data, который имеет отрицательное число?

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, parallax

Добрый день! Атрибут `data` с положительным числом для блока `.left` обрабатывается, блок `.left` меняет по мере прокрутки свое свойство. А если атрибут `data` имеет отрицательное число, как это у блока `.right`, то при прокрутке блоки с классом `.right` остаются неподвижными, т.е. отрицательный отступ не сбрасывается. Помогите, пожалуйста, решить задачу. Спасибо!

```js
$(function() {

var $win = $(window),
    $rev = $('[data-tr]'),
    winH2 = 0,
    winSt = 0;

function reveal() {

  winSt = $win.scrollTop();
  winH2 = $win.height()/2;

  $rev.each(function(i, el){
    var y = el.getBoundingClientRect().top,
        toMiddleMax = Math.max(0, y-winH2),
        idealMarg   = Math.min(+el.dataset.val, toMiddleMax),
        margMin     = Math.min(idealMarg, idealMarg * (toMiddleMax/winH2));
    $(this).css({transform: el.dataset.tr+"("+ margMin +"px)"});
  });

}
$win.on({
  "load resize scroll" : reveal
});

});
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;}
html, body{height:100%; margin:0;}

p {height:250px;}

.left,
.right,
.top {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.left {background:red;float:left;}
.right {background:green;float:right;}
.top {background:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<div class="left" data-tr="translateX" data-val="300"></div>
<p></p>
<div class="left" data-tr="translateX" data-val="300"></div>
<p></p>
<div class="right" data-tr="translateX" data-val="-300"></div>
<p></p>
<div class="right" data-tr="translateX" data-val="-300"></div>
<p></p>
<div class="top" data-tr="translateY" data-val="300"></div>
<p></p>
<div class="top" data-tr="translateY" data-val="300"></div>
<p></p>
```